# Keep getting "No declaration for element" errors. What is wrong with this XML/DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I have created a simple XML and a DTD, but for some reason every single validator I try keep giving me "No declaration for element" errors on every single line. I am not quite sure what I have done wrong as I have only just started looking into XML and DTD, and would appreciate some insight, so I know what I have done wrong and can improve. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated so I know what to do in the future.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!ELEMENT BILLER (RESTAURANTNAME,ADRESS,COMPANYPHONE,CVR)>

<!ELEMENT TIME (DATE,CLOCK)>
<!ELEMENT ORDER (MENUITEM+,CUSTOMER)>

<!ELEMENT RESTAURANTNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ADRESS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT COMPANYPHONE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CVR (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CLOCK (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT MENUITEM (FOOD,REQUEST,REQUESTPRICE?,QUANTITY,PRICETOTAL)>
<!ELEMENT CUSTOMER (TABLE,NAME,SPECIALTYPING,PAYMENTMETHOD)>

<!ELEMENT FOOD (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT REQUEST (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT REQUESTPRICE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT QUANTITY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PRICETOTAL (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT TABLE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT SPECIALTYPING (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PAYMENTMETHOD (#PCDATA)>
]>
<regning id="122">    
<tidspunkt>
  <dato>03</dato>
  <måned>01</måned>
  <år>2020</år>
  <tid>13.40</tid>
</tidspunkt>

<restaurant>
<restaurantnavn>Restaurant Fixi</restaurantnavn>
<adresse>Havstreet 128, 478 Andeby</adresse>
<telefon>81 19 26 18</telefon>
<cvr>29 23 28 00</cvr>
</restaurant>

<kundeinfo>
<bord>3</bord>
<kunde-nr>122</kunde-nr>
<specielt>vegetar</specielt>
<betaling>KONTANT</betaling>
</kundeinfo>

<tjener>
        <fornavn>Lotti</fornavn>
        <efternavn>Andersen</efternavn>
</tjener>

<ordre>
  <menugenstand>
    <madtitel>Vegetar Lakseburger med fritter</madtitel>
    <ekstra>x</ekstra>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <pris valuta="DKK">80</pris>
  </menugenstand>

<menugenstand>
    <drikketitel>Økologisk hvedeøl</drikketitel>
    <ekstra>x</ekstra>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <pris valuta="DKK">45</pris>
  </menugenstand>

  <menugenstand>
    <madtitel>Båd Banannasplit</madtitel>
    <ekstra>Ekstra flødeskum</ekstra>
    <requestprice>10</requestprice>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
  <pris valuta="DKK">55</pris>
  </menugenstand>

</ordre>
</regning>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML document must be *well formed* (syntax ok, one root element, all elements closed, etc) but in addition it can also be valid against a DTD or an XML Schema. In the case of a DTD (Document Type Definition), the DTD governs the *content model*, i.e. what is the root element, what other elements can a specific element contain, what attributes can there be, etc, etc. I would encourage you to actually read the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/). It's not that difficult.

So, in your example, the `<regning>` element is not defined in the DTD, and since XML element names (tags) are *case sensitive*, no element in your XML document matches any ELEMENT declaration in the DTD. To match your XML document, the DTD must start with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE regning [
<!ELEMENT regning (tidspunkt, restaurant, kundeinfo, tjener, ordre) >
<!ATTLIST regning id ID #REQUIRED >
 ... rest of the content model ...
]>
<regning id="122">'
    ...
</regning>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define a DOCTYPE root element to start with.

I do not see a close resemblance between your DOCTYPE definitions and your XML. The first step to fix this would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE regning [
...
```

The rest is unclear.